# disable Expiring MessageGroup with correlationKey log

Tags: spring-integration

Is there a way to disable this log? I ask this because is casusing us huges log files

2014-09-19 09:26:12,217  INFO AbstractCorrelatingMessageHandler:571 - Expiring MessageGroup with correlationKey[XXXXX]

thanks in advance!
Guzmán

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer. You should specify the `lower` logging level for that category:

```
log4j.category.org.springframework.integration.aggregator.AbstractCorrelatingMessageHandler=WARN
```